# Tables in Text Printer - PHP

Tags: php, text, printing

I am trying to orient the text in text printer using php printer_write function but I know it wont work that way. Can you please suggest me some way to have values in table or div so that they are organized.

Below is the code i am using.

```
<?php

include "connect.php";
include "links.php";

$date = DATE('D, d M, Y');
$i=1;
$getData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facturas");

$dataCount = mysql_num_rows($getData);


$handle = printer_open("Generic / Text Only");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_TEXT_ALIGN, PRINTER_TA_RIGHT);
printer_write($handle, $business_name . "        " . $date);
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, $street . ", " . $city);
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, $phone);
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "-----------------------------------");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");

    while($showData = mysql_fetch_array($getData)){

    $serial = $showData['serial'];
    $type = $showData['type'];
    $model = $showData['model'];
    $qty = $showData['qty'];
    $price = $showData['price'];

    printer_write($handle, $qty . " x " . $type . " " . $model . "....." . $price . "\n");
}
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");

printer_close($handle);
```

?>

This code will print alright but the printer_qire code in `WHILE` loop will juest print everything on its each line, working fine as it is supposed to be, but if there is anyway i can have this data in tables?

This is a practice code in local server and I am aware of SQL Injection.

Thanks

Comment: use str_pad for each of your fields to pad out each of the strings with it's column width before printing.

Comment: something like `str_pad(printer_write($handle, "blah blah"), 10)`??

Comment: nevermind... that is backwards ... you should do printer_write($handle, str_pad("blah blah", 10, " "));

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pad all of your strings so that whey are the width of the column that you want. You can do something like define your column widths in an array.

```
 $columnWidths = array(
      "serial"=>25,
      "type"=>15,
      "model"=>50,
      "qty"=>5,
      "price"=>10

 );
```

Then you can apply these column widths to the showData array at the beginning of your while loop like:

```
foreach($showData as $k=>$v){
    $showData[$k] = str_pad($showData[$k], $columnWidths[$k], " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
}
```

So the complete code would look something like this:

```
<?php

include "connect.php";
include "links.php";

$columnWidths = array(
    "serial"=>25,
    "type"=>15,
    "model"=>50,
    "qty"=>5,
    "price"=>10

);
$date = DATE('D, d M, Y');
$i=1;
$getData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facturas");

$dataCount = mysql_num_rows($getData);


$handle = printer_open("Generic / Text Only");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_TEXT_ALIGN, PRINTER_TA_RIGHT);
printer_write($handle, $business_name . "        " . $date);
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, $street . ", " . $city);
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, $phone);
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "-----------------------------------");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");

    while($showData = mysql_fetch_array($getData)){
        foreach($showData as $k=>$v){
            $showData[$k] = str_pad(substr($showData[$k],0, $columnWidths[$k]), $columnWidths[$k], " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        }
        $serial = $showData['serial'];
        $type = $showData['type'];
        $model = $showData['model'];
        $qty = $showData['qty'];
        $price = $showData['price'];

        printer_write($handle, $qty . " x " . $type . " " . $model . "....." . $price . "\n");
    }
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");
printer_write($handle, "\n");

printer_close($handle);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it orients the text well but tries to fetch every column and then given an error of undefined index on columns which i have not included to be fetched.